# GROK Parsing with regex

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I am using the following regexes:

```
INT (?:[+-]?(?:[0-9]+))
VALUE ([0-9]+)
SPACE \s*
DATA .*?
USERNAME [a-zA-Z0-9._-]+
YEAR (?>\d\d){1,2}
MONTHNUM (?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])
MONTHDAY (?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[12][0-9])|(?:3[01])|[1-9])
HOUR (?:2[0123]|[01]?[0-9])
MINUTE (?:[0-5][0-9])
SECOND (?:(?:[0-5][0-9]|60))
ISO8601_TIMEZONE (?:Z|[+-]%{HOUR}(?::?%{MINUTE}))
TIMESTAMP %{YEAR:year}/%{MONTHNUM:monthnum}/%{MONTHDAY:monthday}-%{HOUR:hour}:%{MINUTE:minute}:%{SECOND:second}.%{VALUE:_second}
MESSAGE %{DATA}ERR_SYSTEM%{DATA}
PARSE_ERROR %{TIMESTAMP:ts}%{SPACE}%{USERNAME:type1}%{SPACE}%{USERNAME:slave}%{SPACE}%{USERNAME:type2}%{SPACE}[%{USERNAME:fibre1}/USERNAME:fibre2]%{SPACE}%{MESSAGE:message}
```

Now I have to parse this line:

> 2013/05/13-05:19:16.776 INFO   abcd1   gamereporting
>   [0000000000000000/00000000000000000000]
>   [GameReportingSlaveImpl:0x30bf7699a010].processReport() : Error
>   processing report for id=18014398509852207, type=frostbite_m,
>   error=ERR_SYSTEM

I get the following after the parsing:

```
type1: INFO
slave : abcd1
type2: gamereportin
```

Now type 2 always misses the *'g'*. Why is it happening?

Could somebody provide the correct regex for the above line?

Comment: I already have given what I have tried ..pls help\

Answer (score 17):

Are you using the [Grok Debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/)?

And where is your Grok pattern? I don't see it in your post.

I would use something similar to the following to start off. As you gave no insight as to how you'd like to save the data, you'll have to add that as you figure it out.

```
%{DATESTAMP}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL}%{SPACE}%{WORD}%{SPACE}%{WORD}%{SPACE}(?<some_id>\[\d+\/\d+\])
```

Use the Grok Debugger - it will save you a lot of time.

---

**Update Dec 2022:**

Please try this [link for the Grok Debugger](https://grokdebugger.com/) as it seems they have moved it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this grok pattern as example:

```
%{DATESTAMP:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{WORD:slave} %{WORD:type2} \[%{GREEDYDATA:fibre1}\/%{GREEDYDATA:fibre2}\] \[%{WORD:class}\:%{WORD:pointer}\].%{WORD:method}\(\) \: %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```